# IIS PHP 500 Internal Server error

Tags: php, windows, iis, server

I wanted to setup PHP on my IIS server (Server 2012). Used the Web Platform Installer (because my server knowledge is nearly none) to install some PHP versions and activated 5.4.24 as the current one. Afterwards I enabled CGI by going into Handler Mappings. When I then try to run a basic php script just an echo "test" or phpinfo() I get a 500 server error.

I've gone through several of the topics already on google or stackoverflow but so far I haven't really found a point to start looking into this further. Can this be something related to rights? Because after I installed PHP plesk also failed which was due to rights not being set.

Comment: The point to start with would be your log files which can be seen with the Event Viewer.

Comment: Good point, so far I haven't really found an error there. The last 24 hours, although this 500 error has been popping up a lot when testing there was no error which is shown in the error logs.

Comment: Are you executing the URL on the server or remotely; executing on the server used to give more detailed error reporting.

Comment: I did this remotely indeed, local i got some more info but I seem to be unable to figure out how to log this some more. The error I'm getting is the following:

File monitoring is enabled for a file which could not be found

Module
   FastCgiModule 

Notification
   ExecuteRequestHandler 

Handler
   PHP54_via_FastCGI 

Error Code
   0x80070003

So I assume there is a file which can not be found though I've gone through all the extensions which are enabled and they are all present.

Comment: The issue seemed to be the rights on certain folders which I now set correctly;

Comment: In my case everything was working fine and one day suddenly it gave this error the problem was something strange with microsoft visual c++ 2012 in my case, it was installed and working fine, to solve the problem i went to programs and selected microsoft visual c++ 2012 and click "repair" and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is that when the PHP handler was configured on IIS, the access to the PHP CGI executable (`C:\Users\lextudio\Downloads\php-8.1.9-nts-Win32-vs16-x64\php-cgi.exe`) was not properly set up.

One quick solution is to grant `IIS_IUSRS` group read access on the folder (`C:\Users\lextudio\Downloads\php-8.1.9-nts-Win32-vs16-x64`).